# How can I Create a List of References in Google App Engine Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a `Foo` type in my Google App Engine datastore. I'd like it to link to a series of other `Foo` types, call them `prerequisites`.

I can use the `ListProperty` type to make a list of simple value types but I'm not sure how to do this with references.  What is the recommended approach for doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's (currently) no `db.ReferenceListProperty` in the datastore. You can closely approximate it with a `db.ListProperty(db.Key)`; if you need to retrieve all the referenced keys, you can do a batch `db.get()` on it to retrieve all the referenced entities at once.

Answer (score 0):

References are just keys, which can be represented as strings, so you could use a StringListProperty to store your keys.

Comment: You can also use a `db.ListProperty(db.Key)` property to store the `db.Key` objects directly.